# stack container adaptor construction

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/stack).

1. How do i initialize 5-9 constructors?
2. What the purpose of  member template constructor `template< class Alloc >` ?

For 1st question I have tried various ways but I just cant get it right. For example

    `std::stack<int> first;
    first.push(1);
    first.push(2);
    std::stack<int> second {first, std::allocator<int>()}; // error`

For 2nd question I do not understand what is the purpose of  member template constructor `template< class Alloc>` anyway.  For example vector has a constructor `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc );` which makes it clear that the second parameter is an allocator and it can be initialized as simple as

    `std::vector<int> first {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> second {first, std::allocator<int>()};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like T.C. suspects, it looks like libstdc++ doesn't have those constructors implemented yet. Here is the [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01519_source.html) from their doxygen:

```
128 #if __cplusplus < 201103L
129  explicit
130  stack(const _Sequence& __c = _Sequence())
131  : c(__c) { }
132 #else
133  explicit
134  stack(const _Sequence& __c)
135  : c(__c) { }
136 
137  explicit
138  stack(_Sequence&& __c = _Sequence())
139  : c(std::move(__c)) { }
140 #endif
```

On the other hand, here's a snippet from my Clang's include:

```
template <class _Alloc>
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    stack(const container_type& __c, const _Alloc& __a,
          typename enable_if<uses_allocator<container_type,
                                            _Alloc>::value>::type* = 0)
        : c(__c, __a) {}
template <class _Alloc>
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    stack(const stack& __s, const _Alloc& __a,
          typename enable_if<uses_allocator<container_type,
                                            _Alloc>::value>::type* = 0)
```

Comment: Yep, I got confused a little by some of the commit comments. They implemented `uses_allocator<stack>`, but not the actual constructors taking allocators.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have tested some examples with libc++ and they are working. I thought libstd++ fully implemented c++11 libraries. But I still do not understand the second part of my question. Whats the philosophy/point of making these constructors templates with 
template< class Alloc > stack( const Container& cont, const Alloc& alloc );. Why not 
 stack( const Container& cont, const Allocator& alloc ); ?

Comment: @Constantinos `stack` wraps a container; it has no `Allocator` template argument itself.

Comment: @T.C. Yes yes, now i see! When i was talking about vector i forgot that the Allocator was already passed. Thank you.